# Remove all NULL values in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, null

I have created the following stored procedure to run `exec sp_InsertAirport 'value1','value2', etc...` . However, I get the error listed below. As you can see, I have tried various methods to remove nulls, but none work. How can I successfully remove Nulls in the sp so it can successfully Insert?

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_InsertAirport, Line 128 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Latitude', table 'DB_Airports.dbo.tbl_Airports'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

```
USE [DB_Airports]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('SP_InsertAirport', 'P') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertAirport]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertAirport]
@ICAOCode VARCHAR(4) NULL,
@IATACode VARCHAR(3) NULL,
@AirportName VARCHAR(MAX),
@City VARCHAR(MAX),
@Latitude DECIMAL(8,3), --NOT NULL
@Longitude DECIMAL (11,3), --NOT NULL
@Elevation INT,
@CountryName NVARCHAR(MAX)
...
INSERT INTO tbl_Airports(ICAOCode, IATACode, AirportName, City, Latitude, Longitude, Elevation) 
VALUES (@ICAOCode, @IATACode, @AirportName, @City, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Elevation)

UPDATE tbl_Airports SET Latitude ='0' WHERE Latitude IS NULL
UPDATE tbl_Airports SET Longitude ='0' WHERE Longitude IS NULL

DELETE FROM tbl_Airports WHERE Latitude = 0 AND Longitude = 0

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Comment: Slight detour but something you need to read. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Why are you defaulting values when they are not known? That is the reason NULL exists in the first place. You really should either fix the table design to allow NULL or don't insert the row at all if either of those values is NULL.

Comment: Read the logic in your procedure. Then read what you wrote as your issue. Your code is specifically trying - in a broken, illogical manner - to avoid inserting a row where both latitude and longitude are zero. So it makes no sense to try to replace NULL values with zero if you try to delete them immediately after inserting. Time to step back and thing about what you are trying to accomplish since this seems like a series of poorly designed bandaids for a task that is not well defined.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Airports(ICAOCode, IATACode, AirportName, City, Latitude, Longitude, Elevation) 
    VALUES (@ICAOCode, @IATACode, @AirportName, @City,
            COALESCE(@Latitude, 0),
            COALESCE(@Longitude, 0),
            @Elevation
           );
```

I think `0` is a very poor default because it is a valid value.  There may be airports on the equator.